# Last Character position of a Edit Box

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

Is there is a way to get the last character position of a Edit box?
I mean I need to implement a function to append some text to it's end.

I have studied the messages that could be send or receive by edit control.
But the problem is there is no way to do it directly.

--Alternative:--

The alternative that I thought is to record the current text-position of the
current position when EM_CHANGE was received and update max position integer 
if it's larger than the current maximum position.

```
int edit_box_last_pos = 0;

case WM_COMMAND:
  switch (HIWORD(wParam))   
  {
    case EN_CHANGE:
        // get the current character position //
        if (LOWORD(SendMessage(error_window_edit,EM_GETSEL,(WPARAM)NULL,(LPARAM)NULL)) > max_char_pos )
        {
          max_char_pos =LOWORD(SendMessage(error_window_edit,EM_GETSEL,(LPARAM)NULL,(WPARAM)NULL));
        }

        return 0;
        break;
    default:
    break;  
  }
```

But rather than this, Is there is a way to do this directly?

--Thanks in advance--

Comment: I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12538062/962089

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
length = SendMessage(error_window_edit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)