# malloc call fails after a seemingly small request

Tags: c++, winapi, malloc

```
void StaticControl::addText(LPWSTR text)
{
    lpCurrentText = (LPWSTR)malloc((GetWindowTextLength(hStatic) + 1) * sizeof(LPWSTR));
    GetWindowText(hStatic, lpCurrentText, GetWindowTextLength(hStatic) + 1);

    lpInput = text;
    chInput = (char*)malloc(sizeof (lpInput) *sizeof(LPWSTR)/sizeof(char*));
    chCurrent = (char*)malloc(sizeof (lpCurrentText) *sizeof(LPWSTR)/sizeof(char*));
    wcstombs(chCurrent, lpCurrentText, wcslen(lpCurrentText) + 1);
    wcstombs(chInput, lpInput, wcslen(lpInput) + 1);
    strcat(chCurrent, chInput);
    lpNewText = (LPWSTR)malloc(strlen(chCurrent) * sizeof(char*)); //this is where it crashes
    mbstowcs(lpNewText, chCurrent, strlen(chCurrent) + 1);
    SetWindowText(hStatic, lpNewText);
    return;
}
//where
HWND hStatic;
LPWSTR lpCurrentText;
LPWSTR lpInput;
LPWSTR lpNewText;
char*  chInput;
char*  chCurrent;
```

This code works fine adding text to the control until the string becomes around 20 characters long in which the program crashes. Stepping through the program, it crashes where I allocate memory for the lpNewText buffer. I don't know what's wrong. Visual Studio takes me to the malloc.h header when it crashes.

Comment: You probably want `sizeof(WCHAR) / sizeof(char)`, not pointers, which are equal in size.

Comment: Please be clear: Is this C++ or C code. If it is C++: Do any of the functions require a string allocated by malloc?

Comment: Wait a minute, why are you converting to narrow strings, concatenating them, and converting the result back to a wide string?

Comment: I think @chris has it. Your calculation using pointers resolves to 1 while your characters are probably 2. So you overwrite memory and a subsequent allocation fails while working with corrupt data.

Comment: Basically all of your malloc calls allocate the wrong amount of memory. For example, `chInput` and `chCurrent` are always allocated 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your pointer width. Since this is C++, why are you even using malloc?

Comment: If you want a more C++ way, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537456/how-to-append-text-to-a-textbox/12537569#12537569).

Comment: Can someone edit my code and put it as an answer then? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start I'd recommend that you abandon `malloc` and use C++ memory allocation techniques. Like `new`, `new[]`, `std::vector<>`, `std::string`, `std::wstring` etc.

That said, I can see the following errors in your code:

```
lpCurrentText = (LPWSTR)malloc((GetWindowTextLength(hStatic) + 1) * sizeof(LPWSTR));
// should be sizeof(*lpCurrentText), i.e. size of a wide char 
// and not size of a pointer as you have it

chInput = (char*)malloc(sizeof (lpInput) *sizeof(LPWSTR)/sizeof(char*));
// sizeof(lpInput), sizeof(LPWSTR) and sizeof(char*) are all equal to the
// same thing, the size of a pointer

chCurrent = (char*)malloc(sizeof (lpCurrentText) *sizeof(LPWSTR)/sizeof(char*));
// as above

lpNewText = (LPWSTR)malloc(strlen(chCurrent) * sizeof(char*)); 
// sizeof(char*) is the size of a pointer, not what you want

return;
// rather pointless when the return type is void
```

I don't really know what your code is trying to do so I'm not going to try to re-write it and correct everything. The fundamental problem you have is that you systematically write sizeof(...) and calculate the size of a pointer when you actually want the size of a character element.

Perhaps what you really need to do is throw away all this horrid code and use `std::wstring` to do your concatenation.